# Is it possible to create MimeMessage from String in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mime-message

I fetched emails from gmail server using pop3 with `enough_email` package. Everything works as expected until I updated the flow like fetch emails which is encrypted by PGP encryption. I already achieved the decryption part of email using `OpenPGP` package which gives String in this form

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000da67ad05d5c5dfba"

--000000000000da67ad05d5c5dfba
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

test 3

--000000000000da67ad05d5c5dfba
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">test 3</div>

--000000000000da67ad05d5c5dfba--
```

now I am trying to create mimeMessage object from the string so I can parse it using `decodeTextPlainPart` function. Already tried to create mimeMessage object by using `MimeMessage.parseFromText` function but it's not working as expected, when ever I try to get plain text using `decodeTextPlainPart` function from my created mimeMessage object it returns the same thing which I provided to `MimeMessage.parseFromText` function.
Did I miss something or followed the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

OpenPGP.decrypt function return string with `\n` as line separator but `MimeMessage.parseFromText` works with `\r\n`, when I replace all `\n` with `\r\n` in string then try to create mimeMessage object from the string I get the expected result.